# Multi-Tenant Azure AD authentication with IdentityServer4

Tags: validation, azure-active-directory, token, identityserver4, multi-tenant

I've configured Identity Server 4 and using Azure AD Authentication. Everything works fine if I use a tenant specific Authority URL in identity server. With that, only a user from that tenant can login. I would like to allow multiple domains to login and would like to validate the issuer in the backend.

To support that I need to use common login endpoint for Azure AD and after I login I get the following error when it redirects to signin-aad endpoint of Identity Server. What configuration should I do so that I can validate the issuer manually?

> SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException: IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: 'https://sts.windows.net/94b73406-72db-4abb-a142-adfdfdfdfdbc/'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: 'null' or validationParameters.ValidIssuers: 'https://sts.windows.net/{tenantid}/'.
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateIssuer(string issuer, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)

Comment: If your domains can grow dynamically at runtime then set `ValidateIssuer` to `false` in the `TokenValidationParameters`. If you have predetermined set of domains then add them all to `ValidIssuers`.

Comment: Thanks @VidmantasBlazevicius Just figured that out.

Comment: Do you know where I can find an example of Identity Server 4 and using Azure AD Authentication? I'm struggling to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your domains can grow dynamically at runtime then set `ValidateIssuer` to `false` in the `TokenValidationParameters`. If you have predetermined set of domains then add them all to `ValidIssuers`.